# Visual Studios building and debugging .cpp file without main()

Tags: c++, assembly, visual-studio-2013

Professor just gave us a block of c++ code in order to learn about the debug windows in Visual Studio, however after creating a blank win32 console project and then dragging in the .cpp file I get the missing .exe error message when attempting to debug. I've looked everywhere and no body answers the question completely, I think at this point it must be a problem with the code.

```
    // Test1.cpp : main project file.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace System;

int accum = 0;

int sum (int x, int y)
{
  int t = x + y;
  accum += t;
  return t;
}

int calc (int op1, int op2, int opcode)
{
__asm
{
    mov ebx, opcode;
    test ebx, 0x01;
    jz sub_2;
    mov eax, op1;
    add eax, op2;
    jmp done;
sub_2:
    test ebx, 0x02;
    jz mul_3;
    mov eax, op1;
    sub eax, op2;
    jmp done;
mul_3:

done:
}
}


int main()
{
  int j = -2;
  int i = 0;
  int k = 0;
  float f = 0.0;
  char ch;
  int int_array[5];
  struct customer
  {
      char  name[20];
      short age;
      int   flag;
  };

  struct customer c[10];

  ch = 'A';

  ch |= 0x20;

  i = j * 10 / 5;
  if (i != 0)
      goto cont;
  j = i / 0;

cont: 

  i = sum ( j, -123 );

  printf("decimal = %d, hex = 0x%4x\n", i, i);

  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  int_array[i] = i + 100;

  switch (i) {
      case 100:
        k = k / i;
        break;
      case 200:
        k = k % i;
        break;
      case 300:
      case 400:
        k += 256;
        break;
      default:
        f = 1.0;
  }
  printf("f = %f\n", f);

  strcpy(c[3].name,"Larry King");
  c[3].age  = 65;
  c[3].flag = 10;

  c[3].flag = c[3].flag << 5;
  strcpy(c[3].name,"Larry King                                ");

    k = calc(i, j, 1);
    k = calc(i, j, 2);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where did you drag the file into? If you just dragged it into the editing window, it won't add it to the project and so it wont get compiled. You probably need to drag it into the source files in the "Solution Explorer"

Comment: It compiles and runs for me in a console project after I removed `#include stdafx.h` and `using namespace System`.

Comment: Ninja, It compiles and runs (besides the strcpy warning). The problem arises when I attempt to debug, it says it's missing the files exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does have a main function, which is required for it to work.

As you said the debugger returned a 'missing executable' error, I'm assuming you didn't compile the code, or if so, got some errors which can be found in the output and error windows.

If you're working on a blank project with a single source file, I'd say there is no need to use a pre-compiled header (it may be probably missing, and thus, causing an error).

I suggest you to rebuild the code and try again. If the error is still around, let us know of the Output window contents.

Comment: Getting a warning for strcpy so I replace both strcpy with strcpy_s and apparently that was the problem. Bigger issue is that we are not allowed to modify the professors code and he is running and debugging it with no modification. Well anyways thanks for the help, you led me to take a closer look at the error output.

Comment: It sounds like instead of a warning for `strcpy` you're actually getting an error.  That's a project setting that you can change with no code changes required.  The error message is generally pretty clear how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

A console program must have a main.